# [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry method resolves IP to HOSTNAME without PTR record?

Tags: .net, powershell, dns, nslookup

I am trying to use [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) method to get the HOSTNAME for a given IP from the DNS server.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx), the method first tries to do a reverse lookup on the IP address. In my case this is always successful when I use `Dns.GetHostEntry`.

Now, the strange thing is that for the same IP nslookup doesn't give me anything. It either times out or gives me error: `UnKnown can't find 10.4.202.16: Non-existent domain`. When I look into the DNS server (2008 R2), I can not find any PTR records in de reverse lookup zone. So the fact that nslookup fails doesn't surprise me much.

But what is going on here? Is `Dns.GetHostEntry` using some undocumented ways to obtain the HOSTNAME?

Comment: Do you have only one DNS server?

Comment: @Garath I have 3 which replicate. On all there are no PTR records for the required IP range.

Comment: You can try using IPHostEntry directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856534/gethostentry-doesnt-resolve-the-address-anymore

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, though slightly different on my laptop. It is called "RedMonster". I'm at a facility where I've been given an IP address via DNS. And if I do reverse lookup on the ip address using nslookup I get an address something like "123.123.123.123-dns.organization.ch". However, if I use GetHostEntry to do a reverse lookup, I get "RedMonster.organization.ch". Which makes me think that GetHostEntry is doing something "clever" when run in the default way, and must be using a local cache to do the reverse lookup.

I don't know how to force the system to use DNS, however, which I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Those metods have bugs: http://blog.tyang.org/2011/04/15/problem-with-dns-name-resolution-when-using-system-net-dns-class/  I suggest to use Solution 5 from above post.