# How to use powershell to resolve IP address to hostname for Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, ip-address, hostname

We have both Windows servers and Linux servers in the domain, and I would need to find the hostname based on ip address.

Currently I am using `[System.Net.Dns]::gethostentry('10.254.254.254').HostName` to get the hostname. But this only work when target machine is windows machine. When the target machine is Linux machine, this powershell script doesn't work.

Can someone please help to advise how to use powershell to resolve IP address to hostname for Linux machine?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32662358/478656 - it looks like the .Net method in your code connects to the remote machine to get the hostname, and doesn't use DNS.

Comment: Do you have `PTR` entries setup in DNS for your Linux systems?

Comment: I don't manage the network or the system. So I tried dig -x ip on those linux servers and I do see PTR section as result.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your PS version to 5.1.

I am running 5.1.14409.1005 on Win Srv 2012 and it works for both Unix and Windows.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information - what is 'PS'?