# Get host name by IP address

Tags: c#, dns, hostname

I tried to get the host name by IP address as bellow.

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
string hostName = entry.HostName;
```

But for printer devices. this gives `SocketException` says "No such host is known".

Then I tried with [this](https://github.com/angryip) Ip scanner. It has shown a host name properly (And it is java).

Is there any other way to get host name in C#?

Comment: What is type of `ipAddress`? If it's a string, have you tried using `IPAddress.Parse` and pass it to `Dns.GetHostEntry`?

Comment: Well, not every IP address has a name..

Comment: @vasek it was string. and tried passing 'IPAddress' and the result was same.

Comment: @too_cool but it shows on other third party tools.

Comment: @mhs And what if you `ping -a <ipaddr>`? Does it resolve?

Comment: Probably incorrect ip address. What is the value of the ipAddress variable?

Comment: @vasek Yes it is.

Comment: @falopsy actually the device has static IP and it comes correctly.

Comment: @mhs Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856534/gethostentry-doesnt-resolve-the-address-anymore)?

Comment: @mhs try IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost"); in place of your first line. If that works the error is probably because the ip address is incorrect or some firewall issue.

Comment: @falopsy "localhost" Works fine. And I tried other PC's connected to the network, those are works too. this only happens with printers.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try this way

```
Using System.Printing

 var pri = new PrintServer();
            var queues = pri.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
            foreach (var queue in queues)
            {
                string printerName = queue.Name;
                string printerPort = queue.QueuePort.Name;
             }
```

Comment: thanks, I tried. this gives installed printers. but some printers are not installed,